# jQuery : How can I serialize id after removing an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dragging the elements and incrementing its id I just want to know how can I serialize the id`s after removing elements.

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-remove', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */

        $(this).slideDown();
            $(this).animate({
                "opacity" : "0",
                },{
                "complete" : function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                }
            });

    });
```

**UPDATE :**

1. In here the serialize means ( if suppose I have dragged the elements three times and the id test-clone-1, test-clone-2 and test-clone-3 respectively to each div and now if I remove the second div with id test-clone-2 after removing that the third div with id test-clone-3 becomes test-clone-2
2. To See the id increment please open the console

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pL4Lv6r9/80/)

Comment: what you mean by `serialize the id`s`?

Comment: also in fiddle code where is the code responsible for incrementing the id. You always giving the same id like `test-clone-1`.

Comment: @vijayP I have updated my question

Comment: @vijayP I have updated my fiddle also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Re-numbering Id's `test-clone-X` by adding this loop to `"complete"` function:

```
//Re-numbering id's of each div inside .test class.
$('.test').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).attr("id", "test-clone-" + ( i + 1 ) );
});
```

See [***Updated Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/tnk54537/)

*Inspect element and see the new id's when you removing any element.*